# How to change column name in postgres? (like one name to new name)

Tags: postgresql

In PostgreSQL Don't know how to alter the table - column value?

Alter command for the column value in PostgreSQL

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because no research

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ALTER TABLE IF EXISTS table_name RENAME COLUMN column_name TO new_column_name;
```

Found in the docs [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-altertable.html)